# Nested mapping reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, nested-map

I'm mapping a list of objects in my react app like follows

```
(countrydata !== null) ? Object.keys(countrydata).map((item, key) => {
  return (
    <img src={countrydata[item].image_location}/>
  )
})
```

I also have an array which has the exact number of objects as in the list of objects i have mapped above. I want to display a certain data that is in the objects of the array and i tried doing something like this

```
(countrydata !== null) ? Object.keys(countrydata).map((item, key) => {
  arrayOfObjects.map((arrayItem,key)=>{
    return (
      <div>
        <img src={countrydata[item].image_location}/>
        <span>{arrayItem.name}</span>
      </div>
    )
  })            
})
```

But couldn't achieve the result i wanted. How can i map the array of objects inside the mapping of objects list?

Edit:

My list of objects looks like this (countrydata)

```
place_1:{description:'',image_location:'',location:''}
place_2:{description:'',image_location:'',location:''}
place_3:{description:'',image_location:'',location:''}
```

My array of objects looks like this (arrayOfObjects)

```
0: {distance: {…}, duration: {…}, status: "OK"}
1: {distance: {…}, duration: {…}, status: "OK"}
2: {distance: {…}, duration: {…}, status: "OK"}
```

Comment: Could you please post a tiny example of the objects `countrydata` and `arrayOfObjects`?

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir i have updated it in the question

Comment: Are keys in the first object always like `place_N`? Can there be a missing number like `place_1, place_2, place_5`? The first object should really be an array of objects, that would make things a lot easier

Comment: No.it's always go in ascending order. there won't be any missing number

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir i have done the object mapping part correctly. i just want to display the data in my array in a orderly fashion

Comment: it's not clear what you are trying to achieve with `arrayItem.name`, if `arrayOfObjects` only contains `distance`, `duration` and `status` (no name)... please be more precise about `the result i wanted`

Comment: arrayItem.name was given as a example. Basically i'm getting a response from a API call which has 14 objects. And also i'm getting another response of an array which has 14 objects. I have mapped the objects in first response. What i want is to display distance and duration which are in the array of objects inside the mapped object(1st response)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need another nested `map`. You can `map` them both at the same time using only one `map`, you'll use the index provided to the callback to access the item from the other array/object.

BTW, since the order of object keys is unreliable, I suggest you `map` over the array `arrayOfObjects` and use the index to generate the key that you'll use to access the matching object from `countrydata`:

```
arrayOfObjects.map((arrayItem, index) => {
  let key = "place_" + (index + 1);                      // generate the key to access an object from 'countrydata'. If we are at the first object (index == 0), the key will be "place_1"
  return (
    <div>
      <img src={countrydata[key].image_location}/>       // access the matching object from 'countrydata' and use it
      <span>{arrayItem.name}</span>                      // access the current array item from 'arrayOfObjects'
    </div>
  );
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the two arrays and merge the values from the second array.

```js
const data = {
place_1: { name: 'One'},
place_2: { name: 'Two'},
place_3: { name: 'Three'},
};

const countrydata = [];

const locations = [{distance: {}, duration: {}, status: "OK"},
{distance: {}, duration: {}, status: "OK"},
{distance: {}, duration: {}, status: "OK"}]

Object.keys(data).forEach((key, index) => countrydata.push({ [key]: { ...data[key], distance: locations[index].distance, duration: locations[index].duration }}))

console.log(countrydata);
```

Then render the array like

```
countrydata.map((item, key) => {
 return (
  <div>
    <img src={countrydata['place_' + key].image_location}/>
    <span>{countrydata['place_' + key].name}</span>
  </div>
 )
})
```

Comment: how to access the place_N ? here item means the object key right?

Comment: item = the object ```{
    "place_1": {
      "name": "One",
      "distance": {},
      "duration": {}
    }
  }```

Comment: My arrayOfObjects has keys for each object. I have included how my array looks like . Please take a look. I have trouble accessing values because of that

Comment: For example: 0: {distance: {…}, duration: {…}, status: "OK"}

Comment: ```0``` is a key?